# Error in Vue i18n with TypeScript: "Property '$t' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor'. " . How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-i18n

In project some common function are in separate .ts files.
How can I use i18 in that cases:

```
// for i18n
import  Vue  from 'vue'
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface VueConstructor  {
    $t: any
  }
}
declare module 'vue/types/options' {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    t?: any
  }
}

(()=>{
  const test = Vue.$t('auth.title');
  console.log( test )
})()
```

Return an error:

```
Property '$t' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

we can achieve the same like below

Step 1: create a separate index.ts file inside a i18n folder (you can do it your own way - root level or any where in your app)

i18n/index.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

// register i18n module
Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
   locale: 'nb-NO', //if you need get the browser language use following "window.navigator.language"
   fallbackLocale: 'en',
   messages: {en, no},
   silentTranslationWarn: true
})

const translate = (key: string) => {
  if (!key) {
    return '';
  }
  return i18n.t(key);
};

export { i18n, translate}; //export above method
```

Step 2: make sure to use(import) above in main.ts

main.ts

```
import { i18n } from '@/i18n';

new Vue({ i18n, render: h => h(app) }).$mount('#app')
```

after above configuration we should be able to use translation in any place that we want in our application

Step 3: How to use it in .ts and .vue files

```
// first import it into the file
import { translate, i18n } from '@/i18n';

//this is how we can use translation inside a html if we need
<template>
  <h1>{{'sample text' | translate}}</h1>
</template>

//this is how we can use translation inside a .ts or .vue files
<script lang='ts'>    
  //normal scenario
  testFunc(){
    let test = `${translate('sample text')}`;
    console.log(test );
  }

  //in your case it should be like below
  (()=>{
    const test = `${translate('auth.title')}`;
    console.log( test )
  })()
</script>
```

I hope that this will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I think that in order to use the translate function as a filter you need to add:
Vue.filter("translate", translate);